# disk drive for /home is not ready yet or not present when loading Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 on VMware

Tags: boot, mount, startup, vmware

Hi I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS installed on a VMware station.  It has worked fine before but now when I open the virtual machine it goes thru the normal process of starting and stopping the different processes and then it ends with this :

`The disk drive for /home is not ready yet or not present.                    keys: Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.`

My thinking is I can't press S because I need to mount the drive, and I tried to press M but all I get is the option to perform maintenance via root but I don't know how to do maintenance for this problem.  I guess I could wait but it's already been about 20 minutes.  Does anyone know what I should do?

Edit: I just pressed S to skip mounting, and it sent me to the regular login and everything seems to be working normally.  However I'm still not comfortable with skipping the mount.  Should I be worried about skipping the mount? If not, what is the difference between if it did properly mount and skipping the mount?

Comment: login, open a terminal, post the the output of these commands for more debugging info.  `cat /etc/fstab`, `sudo mount /home`, `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | tail -100`, `dmesg`. Basically, /home failed to mount.  In its place is a blank /home, so things will probably seem quite odd to you until you fix this.

Comment: Thanks your comment actually led me to the fstab file where I added a piece of code.  After I took out the line of code it worked.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to dpb's comment, I checked my /etc/fstab file where I actually added this line of code to the /etc/fstab file:

`LABEL=/home /home ext4 defaults,acl 1 2`

After I deleted the line and restarted it worked fine.