# Disk drive for /home is not ready or not present

Tags: 14.04, boot, mount, lts

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS installed on my lap. It has worked fine before but now when I open the machine it goes through the normal process of starting and stopping the different  and then it ends with this :

```
The disk drive for `/home` is not ready yet or not present. keys: Continue to wait, 
or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

My thinking is I can't press S because I need to mount the drive, and I tried to press M but all I get is the option to perform maintenance via root but I don't know how to do maintenance for this problem
I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606161/disk-drive-for-home-is-not-ready-yet-or-not-present-when-loading-ubuntu-server) : But says login incorrect

Comment: Can we have a history of how you got here?

Comment: Earlier I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8. I like to install linuxmint 18.1 cinnamon. I successfully installed on my PC. Then I saw some free space remains as unused. So I enlarged one of the local disk via Windows storage manager. Then I can't open Ubuntu 14.04. From my personal experiments the home partition remains there as unaffected. 